# Re-fetching with useQuery on argument change

Tags: javascript, next.js, react-query

I am trying to implement pagination using `react-query`. On page change I am updating the page inside `useEffect` using `setArrivals`. For some reason I am always sending the previous value of the `arrivals` as the argument for the `getProductList` function. To fix the issue I am sending the `refetch()` request inside the `setTimeout`. It does work but it doesn't feel right to me. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
const HomePage = ({ newArrivals }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [arrivals, setArrivals] = useState({ ...newArrivals, page: page });

  useEffect(() => {
    setArrivals((values) => {
      console.log({ page });
      return { ...values, page: page };
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
      newArrivalsQuery.refetch();
    }, 0);
  }, [page]);

  const newArrivalsQuery = useQuery(
    ['productListByNewArrivals'],
    () => getProductList(arrivals),
    {
      select: useCallback((data) => {
        return JSON.parse(data);
      }, []),
    }
  );

  return (
    <>
      <NewArrivals
        newArrivalsQuery={newArrivalsQuery}
        page={page}
        setPage={setPage}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const newArrivals = {
    sort: 'createdAt',
    order: 'desc',
  };

  try {
    const queryClient = new QueryClient();

    await queryClient.prefetchQuery('productListByNewArrivals', async () => {
      const newArrivalsResult = await listProduct(newArrivals);
      return JSON.stringify(newArrivalsResult);
    });

    return {
      props: {
        newArrivals: newArrivals,
        dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient),
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
    if (error) {
      return {
        redirect: {
          destination: '/login',
          permanent: false,
        },
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to add the dependencies of your query function *to* the queryKey. react-query is declarative and will re-fetch automatically if the queryKey changes. If you have to reach to `useEffect` and `refetch`, it's likely not the easiest solution:

```
const HomePage = ({ newArrivals }) => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [arrivals, setArrivals] = useState({ ...newArrivals, page: page });

  const newArrivalsQuery = useQuery(
    ['productListByNewArrivals', arrivals],
    () => getProductList(arrivals),
    {
      select: useCallback((data) => {
        return JSON.parse(data);
      }, []),
    }
  );
```

now, `arrivals` are part of the queryKey, which is what you are using in the queryFn in `getProductList`. Now all you need to do is call `setArrivals` and react-query will refetch.

Side note: it looks like `arrivals` is not really *state*, but *derived state*. At least in this snippet, you only call the setter in an effect, which seems wrong. It looks like you want to keep in in-sync  with `page` and compute it every time you call `setPage`, so you can also do:

```
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const arrivals = { ...newArrivals, page: page };
```